Why after TimeFold upgrade, guiScoreDirector.getIndictmentMap() return null
This question is especially for the TimeFold framework.
I have the following code in SolutionBusiness class. The SolutionBusiness class is same which is taken from the Nurse Rostering example with the following modification.
public SolutionOutput exportSolution() {
    guiScoreDirector.calculateScore();
    Solution_ solution = guiScoreDirector.getWorkingSolution();
    return exporter.exportSolution(solution, guiScoreDirector.getIndictmentMap());
}

I have upgraded the code from optaplanner to TimeFold, now I am getting a null value on call the method guiScoreDirector.getIndictmentMap(). It was working fine with Optaplanner 8.4.1.Final. The Version of TimeFold is 1.10.0.

SolutionBusiness (or any other supporting code in the examples module) was never considered a public API and therefore we do not guarantee that it will never change.
In fact, in Timefold Solver 1.10.0 - which you say you are using - the class doesn't exist anymore; the entire examples module has been removed. Since the code you're pointing out is no longer a part of Timefold Solver, I have no way of knowing why it's behaving as you say.

I need to know the scores for each shift assignment. How can I do that in TimeFold?

https://docs.timefold.ai/timefold-solver/latest/constraints-and-score/understanding-the-score#scoreAnalysis
